# Mapstruct and one to many relation

Tags: jpa, mapstruct

I use spring boot 3 with mapstruct

I have an entity with a one to many relation ( bidirectinoal)

```
@Entity(name = "Post")
@Table(name = "post")
public class Post {
 
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
 
    private String title;
 
    @OneToMany(
        mappedBy = "post",
        cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
        orphanRemoval = true
    )
    private List<PostComment> comments = new ArrayList<>();
 
    public void addComment(PostComment comment) {
        comments.add(comment);
        comment.setPost(this);
    }
 
    public void removeComment(PostComment comment) {
        comments.remove(comment);
        comment.setPost(null);
    }
}
 
@Entity(name = "PostComment")
@Table(name = "post_comment")
public class PostComment {
 
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
 
    private String review;
 
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Post post;

}

@Mapper 
public interface PostMapper{

     Post postDtoToPost(PostDto postDto);
}
```

For a new Post, I search a way with mapstsruct to use **addPostComment** to fill correctly jpa relation

```
public class PostDto{

        private Long id;
     
        private String review;
     
        private List<PostCommentDto> comments
    
}



@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface PostMapper {

    Post postDtoToPost(PostDto postDto);

    PostComment postCommentDtoToPostComment(PostCommentDto postcommentsDto);

    List<PostComment> postCommentDtoToPostComments(List<PostCommentDto> comments);

}
```

So when postDtoToPost is call how to do like addComment method in Post?

Comment: Can you add PostDto class to the question?

Comment: have done the update for the to

Comment: Can you explain better what you want to achieve? A small example with some data, can be enough to understand it better and give you the correct answer.

Comment: i add more information

Comment: @roberttrudel have you checked the answer? Is it solving your issue?

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to call addComment method.

All you need is two mappers:

- PostCommentMapper (PostCommentDto to PostComment and
  vice versa)
- PostMapper (PostDto to Post and vice versa)

PostCommentMapper:

```java
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface PostCommentMapper {

    PostCommentMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper(PostCommentMapper.class);

    @Named("toEntity")
    PostComment toEntity(PostCommentDto dto);

    @Named("toDto")
    PostCommentDto toDto(PostComment entity);

    @IterableMapping(qualifiedByName = "toEntity")
    List<PostComment> toEntities(List<PostCommentDto> dtos);

    @IterableMapping(qualifiedByName = "toDto")
    List<PostCommentDto> toDtos(List<PostComment> entities);

}
```

PostMapper:

```java
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring", uses = PostCommentMapper.class)
public interface PostMapper {

    PostMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper(PostMapper.class);

    Post toEntity(PostDto dto);

    PostDto toDto(Post entity);

}
```

you can see more on [invoking other mappers](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#invoking-other-mappers)

The mappers were implemented considering that Entity and Dto have the same field name, so no declared mappings are necessary.
But for custom mappings, you can customize it as you want using @Mapping annotation, for example with [nested bean mapping](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#controlling-nested-bean-mappings)

if you are looking to update the Post entity with new Comments,
you have two options:

1. Declare your own mapping implementation:

```java
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring", uses = PostCommentMapper.class)
public interface PostMapper {

    PostMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper(PostMapper.class);

    @Mapping(target = "comments", expression = "java(updateComments(entity, dto))")
    Post update(Post entity, @MappingTarget PostDto dto)

    default List<Child> updateComments(Post entity, PostDto dto) {
       for(PostCommentDto commentDto : dto.getComments()){
          PostComment commentEntity = PostCommentMapper.INSTANCE.toEntity(commentDto);
          entity.addComment(commentEntity);
       }
    }

}
```

2. Use ADDER_PREFERRED as CollectionMappingStrategy that can be applied to override the default behavior ([tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/java-mapstruct-mapping-collections#collections-mapping-strategies)):

```java
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring", collectionMappingStrategy = CollectionMappingStrategy.ADDER_PREFERRED, uses = PostCommentMapper.class)
public interface PostMapper {

    PostMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper(PostMapper.class);

    Post update(Post entity, @MappingTarget PostDto dto)

}
```